# TestNg using dependsOnMethods and priority violates priority

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, testng

I've seen similar questions here but none seems to resolve the problem.
I've the following code;

```
   @Test(priority=2)
    public void increaseQty(){
       System.out.println("in increase qty");}

   @Test(priority=2,dependsOnMethods={"increaseQty"})
      public void decreaseQty(){
         System.out.println("in decrease qty");}

   @Test(priority=3)
     public void removeFromCart() throws Exception{
          System.out.println("remove qty");}

    @Test(priority=3,dependsOnMethods={"removeFromCart"})
       public void emptyCart() throws InterruptedException{
             System.out.println("empty Cart");}
```

expected sequence of run is

```
increaseQty
decreaseQty
removeFromCart
emptyCart
```

but the actual sequence is

```
increaseQty
removeFromcart
decreaseQty
emptyCart
```

I am not able to understand why its not following the specified sequence.
seems to me like its running independent methods first and then the dependent irrespective of the priority , but no such behavior is mentioned anywhere in the documentation. What should i do to make it run in desired sequence

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't provide priority and depends on together, you can group the tests.
You can do it like :

```
@Test(priority = 1, groups = { "qty" })
    public void increaseQty() {
    System.out.println("in increase qty");
    }

    @Test(dependsOnMethods = { "increaseQty" }, groups = { "qty" })
    public void decreaseQty() {
    System.out.println("in decrease qty");
    }

    @Test(dependsOnGroups = { "qty" })
    public void removeFromCart() throws Exception {
    System.out.println("remove qty");
    }

    @Test(dependsOnMethods = { "removeFromCart" })
    public void emptyCart() throws InterruptedException {
    System.out.println("empty Cart");
    }
```

**Edit:**
Another work around is to change your testng xml to have desciption like:

`<methods>
    <include name="increaseQty"/>
    <include name="decreaseQty"/>
    <include name="removeFromCart"/>
    <include name="emptyCart"/>
</methods>`

so testng will execute it in this manner only.

Comment: I you found this answer correct kindly mark it else for any discrepencies let us know...thanks

Comment: your answer resolves the problem but as per my understanding it is not a best practice to add unwanted dependencies in your test. If any method fails in group qty then the rest will be skipped which I don't want

Comment: The other way u can achieve it is by adding the method names in your testng.xml file in order u want them to execute..like the way i edited in answer or u can name your tests in order like T1_increaseQty, T2_decreaseQty and so on. As far as i have noticed TestNg goes in its execution on the basis of naming of tests in alphabetical order.

Comment: Can u plz confirm whether it helped or not?

Comment: My IDE tells me that groups is redundant when providing dependsOnMethods

Answer (score 0):

If there are 3 or 4 set of sequence then we need to use both priority as well dependency Like 
[>>Seq1-create user, modify, delete  >>Seq2-create group(empty), modify, delete  >>Seq3-create user,create group, add user to group]

in each sequence there is dependency but there is no dependency between sequences.and we need to run each sequence one after other